# How to Order by in($str)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have problem with orderby when I select from table
I have table

```
ID        value
1         2201
2         5412
3         3300
4         6600
5         7700
6         2200
-------------------
My sql query:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ('2','4','6','1','3')
```

Result is:

```
ID        value
6         2200
1         2201
3         3300
2         5412
4         6600
```

And i don't need to sort, I just want to show with position in string

```
ID        value
2         5412
4         6600
6         2200
1         2201
3         3300
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you phrase this in more of a question format?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id IN (2,4,6,1,3)
ORDER BY ID = 2 DESC, ID = 4 DESC, ID = 6 DESC, ID = 1 DESC, ID = 3 DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the value in string is variable. The value in string will change and I don't know it before.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with SQL which does not guarantee the order of the returned tuples. You will have to sort according to that order in your application or create another column as follows:

```
1 2 5412
2 4 6600
3 6 2200

etc...
```

and sort by the new column. Otherwise the code in the application will depend on what language you use to call your sql from.

Regards,

Jason Posit

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id in ('2','4','6','1','3')
   order by FIELD(id, '2', '4', '6', '1', '3')
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc42b/4)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved my problem, my code is:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ($str) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$str)

Comment: you welcome ! if it helped you then make sure to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, my code is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ($str) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$str)
```